# Break list of dictionaries into dictionaries for common elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The problem is a little hard to explain with just the title.

I have a huge list of dictionaries, dict_list, about 18k long. One of the keys on each of them is "PROCESS". The processes are "Etch" and "Depo", and each will repeat for a bit, then change to the other, and back. These are called "runs".

I need to group similar processes together into a list, until the process changes, then insert that list into a "runs" dictionary. Here is a better visual explanation:

```
dict_list = [{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},
             {"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},
             {"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},
             {"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},
             {"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},
             {"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},
             {"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},
             {"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},
             {"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},
             {"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},
             {"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},
             {"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"}]
```

Basically, if I loop over `dict_list`, printing each "PROCESS" line by line, it would look like:

```
>>"Etch"
>>"Etch"
>>"Etch"
>>"Etch"
>>"Depo"
>>"Depo"
>>"Depo"
>>"Depo"
>>"Etch"
>>"Etch"
>>"Etch"
>>"Etch"
>>"Depo"
>>"Depo"
>>"Depo"
>>"Depo"
```

For that example I would have 4 "runs" dictionaries, each with a list of 4 dictionaries.

I would need to group them into lists and then into dictionaries like such:

```
new_dict_list = {
    "run 1": [{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"}],
    "run 2": [{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"}],
    "run 3": [{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"}]
}
```

It would be something like:

- Iterate over each dictionary
- Place the first dictionary in a list,
  and that list into a new dictionary (we call this a run)
- On the next iteration, if dictionary["PROCESS"] is the same, store it
  into the same list and same dictionary
- If dictionary["PROCESS"] changes, store the current dictionary in a
  new list and then into a new dictionary

I'm just not sure how to put this into python logic. I'm still newish at this.

This is what I have so far:

```
prev_process = ""
counter = 0
new_dict_list = {}

for dictionary in dict_list:
  if dictionary["PROCESS"] != prev_process:
    counter += 1
    prev_process = dictionary["PROCESS"]
  new_dict_list["run " + counter] = dictionary
```

I'm feeling there should be a while loop there, "while dictionary["PROCESS"] remains the same, do stuff", but I don't know how to put that into python, or how to break out (because the condition would always be true if I check it like I am now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
dict_list = [{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Depo"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"},{"PROCESS": "Etch"}]
new_d = {'run {}'.format(i):list(b) for i, [_, b] in enumerate(itertools.groupby(dict_list, key=lambda x:x["PROCESS"]), 1)}
```

Output:

```
{'run 1': [{'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}], 
 'run 2': [{'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}, {'PROCESS': 'Depo'}], 
 'run 3': [{'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}, {'PROCESS': 'Etch'}]
}
```

`itertools.groupby` categorizes data based on a single key. In this case, the data is grouped around the value for the `'PROCESS'` key, resulting in nested lists, containing the key value, and all elements that have a matching key value. To create the custom `'run {number}'` key, `enumerate` is used to keep track of the current index of iteration in a clean manner.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your help. I should really get to know itertools too, seems like a powerful set of tools.

Comment: I would only ask for a brief explanation of what is happening on the second part of that dict comprehension, please.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation. I wracked my brain over this for about 4 hours today and finally gave up. I still have much to learn. Appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the lambda function (just trying this out at work today, I didn't have my work laptop during the weekened). The error points at ["PROCESS"] (the key). Not sure what it's expecting there though.

Comment: I'm curious to know whether this worked for you at the time?

Comment: @Mormoran Oh, It is because of the `f-string` that is being used to format the `run` key. Please try now. It worked for me in both Python versions.